# Shared information between some Android activities

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I'm developing my first app. Right now I have been able to implement some activities that work on their own and share information through intents, bundles, etc.

The problem is that a have a list that I manipulate in several activities and I don't want to pass it each time I change my activity. What I want is to have the same list for all the activities so if I change it in Activity1 I'm also changing it in Activity4.

I don't know what would be the best approach to do this. Can anyone guide me a little bit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871509/using-application-class-for-storing-persistent-data-in-android Had asked a somewhat similar question

Answer (score 0):

use databases for storing list items

[here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List2.html) is an example for using listview and database

Answer (score 0):

Write singleton class wich will contain your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom class which inherits from [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. You can get this instance of this class from every activity by calling [getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29); To use your custom application class, you have to register it in the manifest file of your app.

If you really need a database to store you list depends on what your application does. If you want to persist the list when application is closed or shut down by Android then you should store the list items in a database. It would also be possible to write them into a file on the SDCard of the phone. But a database would be the better solution, I guess.